# Getting a random value in ajax GET url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, instagram

*EDIT: I've managed to address the issues above, but the max_id keeps getting returned as the same for every load, so the same 20 photos keep loading.*

I'm trying to pull in Instagram photos from a hashtag, and then using an ajax feed to call the next set of photos when you scroll to the bottom of the page. Problem is, my ajax script is picking up a random value from somewhere and placing it at the end of my GET url, which renders the URL useless.

I've gone over all my code all day and can't find where it's wrong.

**index.php**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$('#imore').bind('click', function(){
    var tag   = $(this).data('tag'),
        maxid = $(this).data('maxid'),
        $c = $('div#instphotos'),
        $newItems = '';

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'ajax.php',
      data: {
        tag: tag,
        max_id: maxid
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        // Output data

        $.each(data.images, function(i, src) {

            var $newItems = $('<div class="mblock"><span class="number">1</span><div class=""><a href="'+data.images[i].src+'?loadtype=iframe" class="imagebox fancybox.iframe" ititle="<div class=&quot;posttitle&quot;>@</div><div style=&quot;float:right;margin-right:15px;&quot;></div><div class=&quot;clear&quot;></div>"><img src="'+data.images[i].thumb+'"></div>').css('opacity', 0); 
            $c.isotope( 'insert', $newItems ).fadeTo('fast', 1); 

        });
        $('#imore').data('maxid', data.next_id);

      }

    });
});
});

<?php
/** Instagram PHP API */
require_once 'instagram.class.php';

// Initialize class with client_id
// Register at http://instagram.com/developer/ and replace client_id with your own
$instagram = new Instagram('19a4efd22cc1442d97057bd1083e3385');

// Get latest photos according to geolocation for Växjö
// $geo = $instagram->searchMedia(56.8770413, 14.8092744);

$tag = 'subarulove';

// Get recently tagged media
//$media = $instagram->getTagMedia($tag);

$media = $instagram->getTagMedia('breakfast',$auth=false,array('max_tag_id'=>$maxID));

// Display first results in a <ul>
echo '<div id="instphotos">';

$i = 1;
foreach ($media->data as $data) {
    echo '  <div class="photo mblock"><span class="number">'.$i.'</span><div class=""><a href="'.$data->images->standard_resolution->url.'?loadtype=iframe" class="imagebox fancybox.iframe" ititle="<div class=&quot;posttitle&quot;>@'.$data->user->username.'</div><div style=&quot;float:right;margin-right:15px;&quot;></div><div class=&quot;clear&quot;></div>">'."\n";
    echo '    <span class="roll"></span>'."\n";
    echo '    <img src="'.$data->images->low_resolution->url.'"></a></div></div>'."\n";
$i++;
}
echo '</div>';

echo '<div id="imore" data-maxid="'.$media->pagination->next_max_id.'" data-tag="'.$tag.'"><a href="#">Load more ...</a></div>';
?>
```

**ajax.php**

```
 require_once 'instagram.class.php';

  // Initialize class for public requests
  $instagram = new Instagram('19a4efd22cc1442d97057bd1083e3385');

  // Receive AJAX request and create call object
  $tag = !empty($_GET['tag']) ? $_GET['tag']: null;
  $maxID = !empty($_GET['maxid']) ? $_GET['maxid']: null;
  $clientID = $instagram->getApiKey();

  $call = new stdClass;
  $call->pagination->next_max_id = $maxID;
  $call->pagination->next_url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{$tag}/media/recent?client_id={$clientID}&max_tag_id={$maxID}";

  // Receive new data
  $media = $instagram->getTagMedia($tag,$auth=false,array('max_tag_id'=>$maxID));

  // Collect everything for json output
  $images = array();
  if($media){
    foreach ($media->data as $data) {
      $src = $data->images->standard_resolution->url;  
      $thumb = $data->images->low_resolution->url;  
      $url = $data->link;

      $images = array();
       foreach ($media->data as $data) {
        $images[] = array(
          $data->images->standard_resolution->url,
          $data->images->low_resolution->url,
          $data->link,
          $data->likes->count
        );
      }
    }

    echo json_encode(array(
      'next_id' => $media->pagination->next_max_id,
      'images' => $images
    ));
  }
?>
```

And in the console whenever it runs the ajax request it returns:
GET http://url.com/ajax.php?tag=breakfast&max_id=1400131855765479&**_=1400114008166**     500 (Internal Server Error)

The bold part is the random value that is getting inserted into the URL.

Comment: is from the `cache: false,` in your AJAX, its the current timestamp to stop the browser sending a cached response, though It shouldn't cause a 500 error. Check your error logs

Comment: I've removed the cache line but it's still giving me the same thing. I do have an error log with these lines:

[15-May-2014 00:57:06 UTC] PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in /home/public_html/ajax.php on line 17
[15-May-2014 00:57:06 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method stdClass::getId() in /home/public_html/ajax.php on line 37

Comment: Line 17 is: $call->pagination->next_max_id = $maxID;
I figured out the Line 37 issue.

Comment: Yep, i was just about to write an answer, your creating a std object `$call = new stdClass;` but then assigning a value to an undefined object with `$call->pagination->next_max_id` you should also assign pagination as a std class also, or use an array, `$call` is used nowhere but in them few lines so keep it simple.

Comment: Also you need to check your $_GET's are set `$tag = !empty($_GET['tag']) ? $_GET['tag']: null;` and do something if there null. Just because your script sent the request dont mean someone wont test its weaknesses or use it as there own API. it happens

Comment: Thanks. I've updated and now it is giving me 
GET http://myurl.com/undefined 404 (Not Found) 

And the error I'm still getting on line 17 [15-May-2014 01:09:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in /home/public_html/ajax.php on line 17

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52715/discussion-between-f8xmulder-and-loz-cherone)

Comment: finally did an example. hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add pagination, you will need to call the pagination method and then the subsequent requests use the next_id, also fixed the issue with the `Strict Standards: Creating default object from empty value... error`

### A Cleaned up Example

```
<?php 
require_once 'instagram.class.php';

// Initialize class for public requests
$instagram = new Instagram('19a4efd22cc1442d97057bd1083e3385');

// Receive AJAX request and create call object
$tag   = !empty($_GET['tag'])     ? $_GET['tag']     : 'subarulove';
$maxID = !empty($_GET['next_id']) ? $_GET['next_id'] : 0;
$clientID = $instagram->getApiKey();

$call = new stdClass;
$call->pagination = new stdClass();
$call->pagination->next_max_id = $maxID;
$call->pagination->next_url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{$tag}/media/recent?client_id={$clientID}&max_tag_id={$maxID}";

// Receive new data
$media = $instagram->pagination($call, 8); //max to load

// Collect everything for json output
$images = array();
foreach ($media->data as $data) {
    $images[] = array(
        'url'   => $data->images->standard_resolution->url,
        'thumb' => $data->images->low_resolution->url,
        'url'   => $data->link,
        'likes' => $data->likes->count 
    );
}


if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    exit(json_encode(array(
        'next_id' => $media->pagination->next_max_id,
        'images' => $images
    )));
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Instagram pagination example using jQuery AJAX</title>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('#imore').bind('click', function(){

        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "./index.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: { tag: $(this).data('tag'), next_id: $(this).data('next_id') },
            dataType: "json"
        });
        request.done(function( data ) {
            $.each(data.images, function(i, src) {
                $('<img src="'+data.images[i].thumb+'">').appendTo("div#instphotos");
            });

            $('#imore').data('next_id', data.next_id);
        });
        request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });

    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="instphotos">
<?php 
foreach ($images as $image){
    echo '<img src="'.$image['thumb'].'">';
}
?>
</div>
<div id="imore" data-next_id="<?php echo $media->pagination->next_max_id; ?>" data-tag="subarulove">
    <a href="Javascript:void(0);">Load more ...</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *sidenote* your also perhaps want to cache the results of the API call, or your use up your daily quota in no time :)

Comment: What would cause a request.fail?

Comment: a 404, json parse error, lots of things basically if the server returns something other then 200 with valid json, whats the error? the example is a copy and paste, dont try and integrate it into your current code till you know what its doing, because your php has a few errors. also check the url for the ajax its index.php in the example.

Comment: I just created a whole new index file, copied and pasted your code in and I got a parserror alert. "Request failed: parsererror"

Comment: check your error logs again, there shouldn't be any issues with the returned json.

Comment: That's what it is. It's a curl issue.

Comment: your need curl, whats your os? tiz easy to install. on linux just run `sudo apt-get -qqy install php5-curl` from ssh

Comment: i'm on a shared host, so no ssh

Comment: It's fine, I can install it on my home machine

Comment: coolbeans, its odd that even your shared host dont have it installed. good luck happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks again for your help man! I'll go ahead and mark this up